# WordPress feeds not indexing in webmaster tools

Tags: seo, wordpress, google-search-console

I don't have much experience about webmaster tools, i just know the basic of the webmaster, and i am not from SEO background, but i just want to know that:

1. Why my blog's RSS Feeds not indexing from webmaster tools?
2. i want to know about Crawl Stat is this stat is good or bad?
3. To submit the RSS into the webmaster is good for indexing the pages or not?? i also submitted the sitemap.

the link of the website is [Webtech Eleven](http://blog.webtech11.com)

[image: Sitemap]

[image]

Comment: What warning message are you receiving?

Comment: It appears those RSS urls are actually "submitted," no? This does not indicate an error that I have seen.

Comment: Just because you have submitted links it doesn't mean Google will index them, there could be a variety of things wrong with the pages themselves that are preventing them being indexed.

Comment: @artlung and what is the PAGE crawled STATS are right?? or where do i know about that stats??

Comment: It looks like in that interface Google considers RSS feeds to be equivalent to sitemaps. The RSS refers to other content. Is the other content being indexed? I see 66 submitted pages and 46 indexed pages. How close is that to the actual content of the site?

Comment: @artlung thanks a lot to being with me, actually my sitemap is fully indexed. But i saw somewhere on the internet that through feeds the blog is indexed fast instead of Sitemap.

Answer (score 1):

I also used to use the plugin recommended by Jeffrey.

However I recently started using the Wordpress SEO plugin from Yoast:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/

I found it is much more advanced and will index images and videos on your site in Google webmaster tools.

With the RSS feeds question, I would not see any advantage to Google picking up your feed. You are better off submitting the feed to sites like Feedburner and Feedage to get links back to all your feed pages.

Answer (score 0):

Its good to not only have a sitemap uploaded to webmaster tools, but also to specify your sitemap file in your robots.txt file. I find the best way to manage this and auto update webmaster tools is to use this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-sitemap-plugin/

It is good to submit the sitemap as it increases the crawl rate. Also on sites of mine that post daily content, my crawl rate is dramatically increased.